# How Do you prevent overwriting of data in a Dictionary through a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, for-loop, dictionary

I have a piece of data that I have to organize before in order to analysed it.

Data (Sample):

> 3.30.67.10    ['2i69A', '1sfkA', '1sfkB', '1sfkH', '2hcnA', '2hcsA', '2hfzA', '2of6A', '2qeqA', '2qeqB', '2wa1A', '2wa1B', '2wa2A', '2wa2B', '4r05A', '4r8rA', '4r8sA', '1pjwA', '2m0sA', '4uifA', '4o6bA', '2vbcA', '3gczA', '1ztxE', '3c5xC', '4ctjA', '4ctkA', '3u1iA', '3u1iB', '3u1jA', '3u1jB', '3c6eA', '3j42A', '3l6pA', '3lkwA', '4al8C', '4gsxA', '4gt0A', '4oigA', '3j8dB', '1p58A', '2m9pA', '2m9qA', '3uzvA', '1uzgA', '3p8zA', '3p97A', '3uzeC', '3uzeD', '3vttA', '2bhrA', '2bmfA', '2fomA', '2fomB', '4m9fA', '4m9iA', '4m9kA', '4m9mA', '4m9tA', '2jlqA', '2jlrA', '2jlsA', '2jluA', '2jlvA', '2jlwA', '2jlxA', '2jlyA', '2jlzA', '2whxA', '2whxC', '2wzqA', '2wzqC', '3uypB', '1yzoA', '1k4rA', '4alaC', '1z66A', '2gg1A', '3ixyA', '2hg0A', '2v6iA', '2v6jA', '4r8tA', '1yksA', '1ymfA', '3evaA', '3evbA', '3evcA', '3evdA', '3eveA', '3evfA', '1p58D', '2b6bA', '1s6nA', '1l9kA', '1oamA', '1oanA', '1ok8A', '1okeA', '1r6aA', '1r6rA', '1thdA', '2p1dA', '3j8dG', '3j8dH', '3zkoA', '4tplA', '4uifB', '4ut6A', '4ut9A', '4utaA', '4utbA', '4utcA', '3g7tA', '3j05A', '4cauA', '4cbfA', '4cbfB', '3j35A', '1tc7C', '2fp7A', '2fp7B', '2g05D', '2ggvA', '2ggvB', '2ijoA', '2ijoB', '2p5pA', '2yolA', '3e90A', '3e90B', '3e90C', '4r8tB', '4c2iA', '2oxtA', '3egpA', '3ircA', '4ffyA', '4ffzA', '4l5fE', '2jqmA', '2jv6A', '4am0A', '4am0Q', '4am0R', '4fg0A', '4bz1A', '4bz2A', '2p3qA', '2xbmA', '3c5xA', '2oy0A', '3i50E', '3iywA', '3j0bA', '3lkzA', '4o6cA', '4o6dA', '4oieA', '4oiiA', '3c6dA', '2r6pA', '2p3lA', '2p3oA', '2p40A', '2p41A', '1urzA', '2px2A', '2px4A', '2px5A', '2px8A', '2pxaA', '2pxcA', '2v8oA', '2wv9A', '3c6dD', '3c6eC', '3j42D', '2z83A', '3p54A', '4hdgA', '4hdhA', '4k6mA', '4mtpA', '4mtpD', '2jsfA', '2r69A', '3c6rA', '3c6rD', '3ixyD', '3iyaA', '3iyaD', '3ixxA', '2r29A', '3evgA', '1df9A', '2qidA', '3j27A', '3j27B', '3j2pA', '3j2pB', '4uihA', '3uzqB', '1befA', '1tg8A', '1tgeA', '3ixxD', '5a1zA', '1n6gA', '1na4A', '1svbA', '4azxA', '4azxD', '4b03A', '4b03D', '4c2iB', '4cctA', '4cctD', '2h0pA', '3uajB', '3uc0A', '3uc0B', '3we1A', '2j7uA', '2j7wA', '3j6sA', '3j6sB', '3j6tA', '3j6tB', '3j6uA', '3j6uB', '3vwsA', '4c11A', '4hhjA', '4v0qA', '4v0rA']

As you can see some of the data has the first 4 digits similar like "1sfk". If they share the first 4 digits that means that they belong to the same structure and I require to store the Unique UniProt code for each full protein code (5 digit, like 1sfkA or 1sfkB) (found in the PDBSum Database) together under that 4 digit code.

For that I created this peace of code:

```
for domain in dDomainSeqSum.keys():# CHANGE TO COMPRESS FILE
        dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain]={}
        for pdb in dDomainSeqSum[domain]:#add sws of a pdb in a variable and later add that variable to the domain thing
            pdb1 = list(pdb)#split is not working
            pdb2 = pdb1[0]+pdb1[1]+pdb1[2]+pdb1[3]
            dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain][pdb2]=[]
            for i in range(len(PDBSum)): #make pdb3 search and then compare to the pdb stored
                if pdb in PDBSum[i]:
                    if "SWS_ID" in PDBSum[i]:
                        line = PDBSum[i].split()
                        if pdb2 not in dDomainSeqSumSWS:
                            dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain][pdb2]=[line[2]]
                        else:
                            dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain][pdb2].append(line[2])
```

After running both of the codes this is the results that I get:

> {'3.30.67.10': {'4c2i': ['G3F5K5'], '2p3l': ['Q9WLZ5'], '4uta': ['Q68Y26'], '4utc': ['Q68Y26'], '4utb': ['Q68Y26'], '1urz': ['Q80E47'], '3l6p': ['P17763'], '1tge': ['P27914'], '3evb': ['P03314'], '2vbc': ['Q2TN89'], '3eva': ['P03314'], '3evf': ['P03314'], '3evg': ['P29991'], '3evd': ['P03314'], '3eve': ['P03314'], '2p1d': ['P12823'], '3j42': ['Q3BCY5'], '2jlx': ['Q2YHF0'], '2jly': ['Q2YHF0'], '2jlz': ['Q2YHF0'], '2jlu': ['Q2YHF0'], '2jlv': ['Q2YHF0'], '2jlw': ['Q2YHF0'], '1oke': ['P12823'], '2jlq': ['Q2YHF0'], '2jlr': ['Q2YHF0'], '2jls': ['Q2YHF0'], '2wv9': ['P05769'], '2z83': ['P27395'], '4hdh': ['P27395'], '2hcn': ['P14335'], '2oxt': ['A0EKU1'], '1tg8': ['P27914'], '4hdg': ['P27395'], '4ut9': ['Q68Y26'], '3e90': ['P06935'], '4am0': ['Q58HT7'], '4ut6': ['Q68Y26'], '1ok8': ['P12823'], '4ffy': ['Q9J7C6'], '4ffz': ['Q88640'], '4b03': ['G3F5K5'], '2m9p': ['P14337'], '2m9q': ['P14337'], '4fg0': ['P09732'], '4azx': ['G3F5K5'], '2hcs': ['P14335'], '4hhj': ['Q6DLV0'], '4mtp': ['P27395'], '3j8d': ['P12823'], '3uc0': ['P09866'], '4l5f': ['Q8BE40'], '4m9t': ['Q91H74'], '4m9k': ['Q91H74'], '4m9i': ['Q91H74'], '2of6': ['P14335'], '2px5': ['P05769'], '4m9m': ['Q91H74'], '4m9f': ['Q91H74'], '3j0b': ['Q9Q6P4'], '5a1z': ['G9FRP5'], '4r8r': ['C1KBQ3'], '4r8s': ['C1KBQ3'], '1l9k': ['P12823'], '1svb': ['P14336'], '4r8t': ['O90417'], '2hfz': ['P14335'], '2v6j': ['Q32ZD5'], '3zko': ['P12823'], '2ggv': ['P06935'], '2v6i': ['Q32ZD5'], '3u1j': ['Q5UB51'], '3u1i': ['Q5UB51'], '4oig': ['P17763'], '4ala': ['Q7TGD1'], '3p97': ['P27915'], '3p8z': ['P27915'], '2pxc': ['P05769'], '4gsx': ['P17763'], '2pxa': ['P05769'], '4oii': ['Q9Q6P4'], '1bef': ['Q9Q4T1'], '3evc': ['P03314'], '3j05': ['Q689G3'], '3egp': ['Q9J7C6'], '2yol': ['P06935'], '2v8o': ['P05769'], '4r05': ['C1KBQ3'], '1n6g': ['P14336'], '3lkz': ['Q9Q6P4'], '4cau': ['Q689G3'], '2px2': ['P05769'], '2gg1': ['P29837'], '4al8': ['P17763'], '2px4': ['P05769'], '3lkw': ['P17763'], '2r69': ['P18356'], '2r6p': ['Q66394'], '3j6s': ['Q6DLV0'], '3j6u': ['Q6DLV0'], '1sfk': ['P14335'], '1z66': ['P29837'], '3uaj': ['P09866'], '3iyw': ['Q9Q6P4'], '3j35': ['E7FLK7'], '4k6m': ['P27395'], '2fom': ['Q91H74'], '3vws': ['Q6DLV0'], '3vtt': ['P27915'], '3iya': ['P18356'], '2p5p': ['P06935'], '2hg0': ['Q91R00'], '2jqm': ['Q6DV88'], '2p41': ['Q9WLZ5'], '4v0r': ['Q6DLV0'], '4tpl': ['Q5SBG8'], '1yks': ['P03314'], '4bz1': ['Q7TGC7'], '4bz2': ['Q7TGC7'], '1thd': ['P12823'], '2m0s': ['Q9YKL3'], '4cbf': ['E0WXI2'], '3ixx': ['Q3I100'], '3ixy': ['P18356'], '2px8': ['P05769'], '1ztx': ['Q91KZ4'], '2fp7': ['P06935'], '4uif': ['E0WXJ3'], '4uih': ['P14340'], '3uzq': ['P27909'], '4c11': ['Q6DLV0'], '1p58': ['Q9WDA7'], '4cct': ['G3F5K5'], '2r29': ['P29991'], '2p40': ['Q9WLZ5'], '1na4': ['P14336'], '1ymf': ['P03314'], '3uzv': ['P07564'], '1r6r': ['P12823'], '3c5x': ['Q6H1E5'], '2xbm': ['C0LMU5'], '3g7t': ['Q689G3'], '2g05': ['P06935'], '1r6a': ['P12823'], '3uze': ['P27915'], '2whx': ['Q2YHF0'], '3p54': ['P27395'], '1k4r': ['C3V005'], '3i50': ['Q9Q6P4'], '3c6d': ['Q3BCY5'], '3c6e': ['Q3BCY5'], '4o6c': ['Q9Q6P4'], '4o6b': ['P29990'], '4o6d': ['Q9Q6P4'], '2ijo': ['P06935'], '2wa2': ['Q8QL64'], '1tc7': ['P06935'], '3j27': ['P14340'], '2wa1': ['Q8QL64'], '3gcz': ['Q7T918'], '2p3q': ['Q20IJ2'], '2jsf': ['P18356'], '3we1': ['P09866'], '1df9': ['P14340'], '4gt0': ['P17763'], '3c6r': ['P18356'], '3j2p': ['P14340'], '3irc': ['Q9J7C6'], '2oy0': ['Q9Q6P4'], '3uyp': ['Q2YHF0'], '2qeq': ['P14335'], '2jv6': ['Q6DV88'], '2qid': ['P14340'], '1oan': ['P12823'], '1oam': ['P12823'], '2b6b': ['Q9WDA7'], '2bmf': ['Q91H74'], '2i69': ['Q80QJ9'], '2j7w': ['Q6DLV0'], '4v0q': ['Q6DLV0'], '1yzo': ['P29838'], '1s6n': ['Q913C7'], '4oie': ['Q9Q6P4'], '2bhr': ['Q91H74'], '3j6t': ['Q6DLV0'], '2p3o': ['Q9WLZ5'], '4ctk': ['A9LIE0'], '4ctj': ['A9LIE0'], '2j7u': ['Q6DLV0'], '1pjw': ['Q9J0X3'], '1uzg': ['P27915'], '2h0p': ['P09866'], '2wzq': ['Q2YHF0']}}

As you can see, the 1sfk is overwritten, it should have 3 individual UniProt Codes

Comment: Please create a **minimal** working example that shows your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two places you have issues (as the other answer also indicates) -

1. First is where you write `dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain][pdb2]` as an empty list - `dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain][pdb2]=[]` .
2. Second is in the condition - `if pdb2 not in dDomainSeqSumSWS:` - this would always be `False`, since `pdb2` is a key in `dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain]` dictionary not `dDomainSeqSumSWS` dictionary.

You actually do not need either of the above things, instead you should look into `dict.setdefault` , which is made for this . Example -

```
for domain in dDomainSeqSum.keys():# CHANGE TO COMPRESS FILE
    dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain]={}
    for pdb in dDomainSeqSum[domain]:#add sws of a pdb in a variable and later add that variable to the domain thing
        pdb2 = pdb[:4] #you do not need to convert to list for indexing and you can slice the first four characters off.
        dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain][pdb2]=[]
        for i in range(len(PDBSum)): #make pdb3 search and then compare to the pdb stored
            if pdb in PDBSum[i]:
                if "SWS_ID" in PDBSum[i]:
                    line = PDBSum[i].split()
                    dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain].setdefault(pdb2,[]).append(line[2])
```

`dict.setdefault` takes `key` as first argument and default value as second argument, and sets the value if the key is not present in the dictionary and returns that value. Otherwise if the key is present in the dictionary it simply returns the value for that value.

Also, I changed the line where you convert `pdb` to a `list()` which is not required for indexing (you can index strings) and you can use *slicing* to take the first four characters from the string.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use dic.setdefault before but I was unable to put it properly. Your insight help me a lot and help me make my code simpler. I really appreciate your help in correcting and making my program more effective. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain][pdb2]=[]
```

there you overwrite the previous list. you should check if the pdb2 key already exists in the dDomainSeqSumSWS[domain] dict.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about it. Your advice help me a lot!